# Stripe payments is not being created in django. It says token is submitted successfully, but it does not show in stripe account

Tags: django, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

when i created a stripe checkout form, i set up everything as the docs said. When i submit the form (test keys), it says that the token was created successfully, but it does not show in the stripe account dashboard.

settings.py

```
 STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = "itsthestripesecretkeyfromaccount"
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "itsthestripepublishkeyfromaccount"
```

views.py

```
def checkout(request, **kwargs):

    item = Shop.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get('pk', "")).first()

    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY




    publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.GET.get['stripeToken']  # Using Flask
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=10.00,
            currency='usd',
            description="Testing",
            source=token,
        )




    context= {'publishKey':publishKey,
              'item':item}
    return render(request,"checkout/checkout.html",context)
```

checkout.html

```
<html><head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style media="screen">
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f8f9;
  color: #6b7c93;
}

*, label {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-variant: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #32325d;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, .11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
  transition: all 150ms ease;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(50, 50, 93, .10), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  background-color: #43458b;
}

form {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 120px;
}

label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#card-errors {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  color: #fa755a;
}

.form-row {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}

.token {
  color: #32325d;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 670px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#stripe-token-handler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 100px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.1),
    0 15px 35px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.15),
    0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

#stripe-token-handler.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}

/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeElement {
  box-sizing: border-box;

  height: 40px;

  padding: 10px 12px;

  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;

  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  <form action="." method="POST" id="payment-form">
      {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement StripeElement--empty"><div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame5" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-31bf44cd4b7f3b6da4e3f1268a2aa532.html#style[base][color]=%2332325d&amp;style[base][fontFamily]=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Helvetica%2C+sans-serif&amp;style[base][fontSmoothing]=antialiased&amp;style[base][fontSize]=16px&amp;style[base][::placeholder][color]=%23aab7c4&amp;style[invalid][color]=%23fa755a&amp;style[invalid][iconColor]=%23fa755a&amp;componentName=card&amp;wait=false&amp;rtl=false&amp;keyMode=test&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js%2Felements%2Fquickstart&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; user-select: none !important; height: 19.2px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div></div>

      <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>

    <button>Submit Payment</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div id="stripe-token-handler" class="is-hidden">Success! Got token: <span class="token"></span></div>


<script nonce="">  // Create a Stripe client.
  var stripe = Stripe('{{ publishKey }}');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  var style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  // Submit the form with the token ID.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }

  var successElement = document.getElementById('stripe-token-handler');
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').addEventListener('click', function() {
    successElement.className = 'is-hidden';
  });

  // Not in demo.
  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    successElement.className = '';
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = token.id;
  }
</script><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeController1" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/controller-d87ddc0145c66826814f1428b5e7b170.html#apiKey=pk_test_6716BBCWhzb1IsIdnonD5MSL00cUgtEOeV&amp;stripeJsId=033a2233-e2e5-4b9d-8fba-1b32c0755684&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com&amp;referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstripe.com%2Fdocs%2Fstripe-js%2Felements%2Fquickstart&amp;controllerId=__privateStripeController1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; visibility: hidden !important; position: fixed !important; height: 1px !important; pointer-events: none !important; user-select: none !important;"></iframe>

  <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeMetricsController0" al
```

I am currently trying to make the payments go through from django website, and it shows in the dashboard of the strip account. Unfortunately, I am unable to figure this out. I have been trying to change things around, but i cant seem to understand what i have to do. If you could, can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

I see in the API requests it says success, but it dont show on the dashboard

Comment: What requests do you see in your stripe dashboard logs, https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs, a request to `/v1/tokens`, a request to `/v1/charges` or nothing?

Comment: I figured it out. I;m just having trouble actually getting the shipping address in stripe now